# Can't scrape names from a table using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape names from a table populated upon selecting some options in a webpage. This is the [options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/img8G.jpg) to generate the table in that site. however, When I try doing the same using the script below, I always get status 500. I got success using selenium, so I'm not after any solution based upon selenium.

[webpage address](https://portal.sulamericaseguros.com.br/main.jsp?lumPageId=8A488A0C15813A720115814200FE046B&lumChannelId=8A488A0C15813A72011581407CCF0168&lumRTI=sai.service.redereferenciada.detalhes_plano&lumRTSI=8A619BA6464E931F01465CE644FD3EAB&lumRCli=1&codTipoNegocio=S&codProduto=&planoProduto=&codTipoContrato=21&planoANSTipoContrato=Cl%C3%A1ssico%20Apartamento)

I've written so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://rederef-saude.appspot.com/proximidade/prestador/buscar?'

params = {
    'canal': '1',
    'latitude': '-23.5505199',
    'longitude': '-46.63330939999999',
    'categoria': '1',
    'produto': '557',
    'plano': '18051',
    'nome': '',
    'qualificacoes': '',
    'prefixoEmpresa': '',
    'empresa': '',
    'especialidade': '',
    'procedimento': '',
    'tipoPesquisaProcedimento': '1',
    'raio': '200000'
}

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36',
    'referer': 'https://rederef-saude.appspot.com/rederef/buscaPrestadores?login=publico&canal=1&data=23/04/2021&hora=00:16:55&tipoProduto=M&produto=557&plano=18051',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'captcha-token': ''
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    res = s.get(link,params=params)
    print(res.status_code)
```

> How can I scrape the names from that table using requests?

Comment: Don't put the `?` in your URL.  `requests` will add it when adding your parameters.  You're sure it is a GET request, and not POST?

Comment: Yep, it's a get requests.

Comment: something about recaptcha?

Comment: When I created the script using selenium, I didn't encounter any captcha, so I suppose it is a placeholder.

Comment: Chrome doesn't present you with a captcha either but if you record the session from F12 network tab there's a lot happening there, not too familiar with recaptcha but I guess it's something important. Does selenium set something in the captcha-token parameter?

Comment: I highly doubt that because I din't use any headers while automating the same using selenium @filippo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Checking the requests it does have recaptcha protection its just that its in a invisible mode which only comes to display if required and this would even need cookies from first call or else it will give invalid session error so for recaptcha automated solution(Paid but pretty cheap) their various providers for it for ex:2Captcha,Anti-Captcha,CapMonster,etc
I Have used 2Captcha for it you could follow the below code.
Reference to [2Captcha Library](https://pypi.org/project/2captcha-python)

```
import requests
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha

solver = TwoCaptcha('Twocaptcha API KEY')
result = solver.recaptcha(sitekey='6LdOzkUaAAAAANV9z7gQOokV2kNWI8WI_eSH80vC',
                          url='https://rederef-saude.appspot.com', invisible=1)["code"]
params = {
    'login': 'publico',
    'canal': 1,
    'data': '23/04/2021',
    'hora': '04:10:41',
    'tipoProduto': 'M',
    'produto': 557,
    'plano': 18051
}
cookies = requests.get(
    'https://rederef-saude.appspot.com/rederef/buscaPrestadores', params=params).cookies

headers = {
    'captcha-token': result,
}
params = {
    'canal': '1',
    'latitude': '-23.5505199',
    'longitude': '-46.63330939999999',
    'categoria': '1',
    'produto': '557',
    'plano': '18051',
    'nome': '',
    'qualificacoes': '',
    'prefixoEmpresa': '',
    'empresa': '',
    'especialidade': '',
    'procedimento': '',
    'tipoPesquisaProcedimento': '1',
    'raio': '200000'
}
response = requests.get('https://rederef-saude.appspot.com/proximidade/prestador/buscar', headers=headers,
                        params=params, cookies=cookies)

print(response.json())
```

Don't forget to update the `Twocaptcha API KEY` in the above Code.
You could use any provider you feel okay with.
Output would be in json so no need to use `BeautifulSoup`
Output:
[image: output]

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: On the page where Recaptcha is located, you could use that page's URL in the solver or only the main domain as at the end, and I guess the solver would send an only domain to the solver server. I mistakenly used the ajax URL, but the domain is the same for both, so it does not matter. I modified the code with the base domain only.